Visual glitches/flickering (GUI windows) in Ubuntu 24.04
I'm experiencing a weird visual glitches related to system interface windows. I didn't have any problems in apps yet (Firefox, Thunderbird, Figma, Devkinsta, and many other apps work fine). Examples (Settings menu):

Wallpapers section in Appearance -> Wallpapers are displayed partially when moving up/down.
Search bar is flickering.
Dropdown menus are glitching/flickering/disappearing/hanging size.

It's a fresh install. I have Ubuntu 22.04 on my secondary drive and everything is OK there, 0 problems (I'm using it with the same notebook). Graphics driver on the both systems is nouveau. I didn't install any proprietary drivers, just Ubuntu 24.04, installed, updated and upgraded today. I didn't change anything. I also tested Ubuntu 24.10, and didn't have any visual problems with it. It only happens in 24.04. I could just stay with 24.10, but I prefer use an LTS version.
Can be this a problem with a Wayland display server?
Video link: https://imgur.com/a/yydrzFq
The graphics card on this old notebook is NVIDIA Quadro FX 2700M. I was trying to install the 340 driver from the NVIDIA website, but there was a conflict with rivafb. Finally I aborted the installation. When I disable the nouveau driver, the GUI looks normal, but everything is slow and the mouse cursor is leaving temporary glitches (it's leaving its own duplicates for a 1-3 seconds). at
It's weird that I have this problem on Ubuntu 24.04 but not on 22.04 and 22.10.
